# opengl development packages are 404 on ubuntu 18? driving me insane

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, opengl

Initial problem:

I need to compile an OpenGL program... which returns the error:
gl.c:5:10: fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

so I try installing:

**command**:

```
sudo apt install freeglut3-dev.
```

which returns,

```
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 mesa-common-dev amd64 18.3~git1810120730.26a10e~oibaf~b
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgl1-mesa-dev amd64 18.3~git1810120730.26a10e~oibaf~b
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa-common-dev_18.3~git1810120730.26a10e~oibaf~b_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dev_18.3~git1810120730.26a10e~oibaf~b_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: Aborting install.
```

How hard can this be? Please help.

Comment: Does it work after you run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: tried it. but no.

Comment: Those packages seem to be ahead of released packages even for for 19.04. So, if you are getting packages directly from the developers, the answer is, it can be very hard. :)

Answer (score 1):

found it.

answer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/mesa
```